# REST-like HTTP POST request with JSON

Tags: rest, http, linux

I am coding a poof-of-concept throw-away GCC plugin (see [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2019-04/msg00133.html) for more context) which would use the HTTP 1.1 protocol to interact with my [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) (GPLv3+ code on [github](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/), but unreleased; draft technical report [here](https://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf)) system (which provides some Web & HTTP service using `libonion`). Both server and client are on the same trusted local area network (so insecurity concerns related to HTTP vs HTTPS are out of scope).

In my limited understanding, my GCC plugin would be some [RESTful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) client (however, I don't fully understand yet what that exactly means). Morally that plugin is doing some kind of RPC (or even JSONRPC) using HTTP transport.

That plugin will use the [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/http-post.html) easy interface and make a [POST request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)), inspired by [this example](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/http-post.html).
For good internal reasons, I would prefer the data sent in that request (from plugin to `bismon`) to be some [JSON](https://json.org/) encoded data and I will use the json-cpp library in that plugin.

It is obviously simpler to me to send, as [CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.html), the entire JSON object and avoiding encoding it a second time as [`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#The_application.2Fx-www-form-urlencoded_type) MIME type.

**Is it reasonable to do so, so just send an `application/json`  data in the `POST`  request?**

Most examples I see are using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

And I might later want to do some similar REST-like request using the `curl`  command. Then should I use something like `curl -b "BISMONCOOKIE=n000001R3dDxLtW8g_1pHEXatdVWO" -d '{"x":1,"y":2}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://localhost:8086/`  or should the `-d`  be replaced by   `--data-raw`  ?

PS. Bismon already has the code for serving HTTP POST requests using [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/), and I would like to reuse the same code (for HTTP requests coming from my GCC plugin thru `libcurl`, not from a real browser like Firefox)

Comment: If the server accepts "application/json", yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, sending POST requests as `application/json` with the body being a JSON object is common in REST and REST-like interfaces over HTTP.

In fact, sending a `Content-Type` header of `application/json` for an HTTP request is often how a client communicates to a REST-like web service that the request body should be expected to be formatted as JSON. This is referred to as [content-negotiation](https://restfulapi.net/content-negotiation/).

Comment: And what about  `curl`  as in my edited question? `-d`  or `--data-raw` ?

Comment: It looks like `--data-raw` can be used when you provide the body inline, as in your example. If you want to provide the POST body from a file, you can use e.g. `-d @some-filename.json`.